# Help Setting Up a MariaDB server

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to setup a MariaDB but I can't figure out what's wrong

### Installation Prosses

I did the following commands:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install mariadb-server

sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

and it simply doesn't work

### Errors ⛔

First Error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

So I tried to start the server
Second Error

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.34 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-08-08 11:41:57 IDT; 13min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
   Main PID: 4674 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.34 database server...
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 sh[4671]: [108B blob data]
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 sh[4671]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 mysqld[4674]: [98B blob data]
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 mysqld[4674]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 08 11:41:57 Server-3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed a step in the installation process. After installing you need to configure mariadb 1st.

> Fatal error in defaults handling

is about missing a configuration.

See step 3 in the [installation procedure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-20-04): it says optional but this part is mandatory if you pressed N at step 2 at "set root password". And you need to press N for non-root systems like Ubuntu.

---

From TS found on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/812719/mysql-mariadb-not-starting):

You can reset by removing all files in `/var/lib/mysql` and then regenerate all files with `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: I fixed the starting problem by removing all files in the `/var/lib/mysql`

then regenerating all files with `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

found a similar issue on [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/812719/mysql-mariadb-not-starting)

Comment: cool Ill add it to the answer :D